# Capturing and play video a certain period of time

Tags: c#, php, .net

i would like to capture video from a cam. For example; get the captured video time is 5 minutes.
I would like to play captured video between 1 to 3 minutes by a clicked button. Do you have any suggestion how to do this with c#.net or php? And can you suggest a component?

PS. Sorry for my bad english. Thank you already now for your help.

Comment: what is the source of the video? PHP is a server side language so it could connect to the cam directly - you would need some kind of client to upload the video.

Comment: Actually i want to capture video on hardisk then i want to play that. But if captured video time lenght is 5 minute, i would like start for playing that first minute to third minute from a button or command. This is important for me. I read many tutorials about capturing and playing video. Bu i could not find about playing video as i would. I know php needs a client side tecnology approach. I can capture video from a cam with php. But i can't play video in flash as i wrote. Your suggest can be over .net desktop tecnoology and can be over compenent.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side language so would need a Client Side Browser Technology like Flash.

But it's perfectly plausible with c# (If your not talking about ASP.net, as this would need the same approach as PHP) check out these links for some source on how to do this:

- http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/93476-Programatically-Using-A-Webcam-In-C
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/810262008070218AM/8.aspx
- http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1339&lngWId=10

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much. But i do'nt need capture video. I need to play video a certain period of time.